# Gutenberg Preview missing styles (only in preview, not in editor)

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a custom Gutenberg Block created with **Javascript** & **PHP** which is missing its preview styles.
The preview should look alike to the one you see in the editor behind it.

[image]

I have **webpack** that compiles all the styles for **ALL the blocks** into one **single** CSS file.
The `block.json` file is included via PHP:

```
register_block_type(
        $directory . '/cover/block.json',
        [ 'render_callback' => 'render_block_cover' ]
    );
```

The styles file is included like follows:

```
    ...
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'c_wp_enqueue_scripts' ], 100 );
    add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', [ $this, 'c_wp_enqueue_scripts' ], 100 );
    ...
```

```
function c_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    ...
    $file_with_path_css = apply_filters( 'get_file_from_dist', 'index.css', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-styles', $file_with_path_css, '', $theme->Version, 'all' );
}
```

I wonder if the styles have to be included via the reference in `block.json`. However with Wordpress 5.9 in earlier projects with a similar structure, the preview did actually work.
However those blocks were not registered in PHP, just in Javascript.

**Q: What might the cause be, that the preview does not show any styles?**

What I can exclude is, that it is a CSS hierarchical mistake. No styles seem to work, even if they are directly on the block without a parent.

Answer (score 2):

As your block has a PHP render callback, I would first check your function, `render_block_cover()` uses `get_block_wrapper_attributes()` to apply the [dynamic blocks classnames](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-supports-in-dynamic-blocks/). The block preview is rendered inside an `<iframe>` with the blocks CSS classnames applied. If the styles are "missing" and present in your CSS, its likely to be an issue with the classnames not being applied to the block when rendered.

In your render function, the classnames should be applied by using `get_block_wrapper_attributes()`, eg:

**php**

```php
function render_block_cover( $attributes, $content, $block ){
    $wrapper_attributes = get_block_wrapper_attributes();
    $content = '<h2>Heading</h2>'; // This would be the dynamic content

    // The returned block content has the block wrapper applied, a <div> in this example
    return sprintf( '<div %1$s>%2$s<div>', $wrapper_attributes, $content );
}
```

If the render callback is correct, next check the `name`, `style` and `editorStyle` in block.json are correct/match your CSS:

**block.json**

```json
{
    "name": "myblock/cover",
    ...
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./index.css"
}
```

The generated classname would be `.wp-block-myblock-cover` for this example block. If your block has variations or [block styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-styles/), the generated class could be different and can also be overridden with:

```
get_block_wrapper_attributes(array( 'class' => 'my-special-classname'))`
```

**Note:** If your *block.json* has `editorStyle` and `style` defined, `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', ...)` and `add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', ...)` are not required in PHP. The CSS is loaded from the blocks.json when the block is registered in PHP:

```php
register_block_type(
    $directory . '/cover/block.json',
    [ 'render_callback' => 'render_block_cover' ]
);
```

Finally, double-check you've cleared your browser cache when testing; its sometimes as simple as this when all else fails.

Comment: In general very good advice, however I have this with all my blocks. Simple static ones i render with ``save()`` and others are rendered with PHP. Both have no styles in the preview, however the back and the front-end both are displayed in their full glory.

The CSS (as described in the question) is all loaded with one global CSS file. So it is never referenced in the ``block.json`` files.

Are you saying, global styles will not work? If I add ``"editorStyle": "file:myGlobalStyle.css"`` to every file, it might include the file multiple times.

Comment: From my last projects I reacall it *should* work even with global styles.

Comment: @Frizzant Thanks for the feedback and additional information. I have a block project configured in a similiar way with the CSS compilied into one global stylesheet. On second look at your question, one difference between your example to mine is `wp_enqueue_style( 'my-styles', ...)`, instead of "my-styles", I use the block script handle, eg `myblock-cover` if block.json  contains `"name": "myblock/cover"`

Comment: I just found out that the styles actually do render, however ONLY when i run the ``yarn build`` script. Not with the `yarn dev`. We had that with the other project too I can recall.
Closer to the solution, but more confused.

Comment: I would think then its sounding like a caching issue with index.css - is this stylesheet output into a separate build directory where as the dev version is not?